# Hard drive in a notebook doesn't seem to work inside an adapter (optical drive replacement)

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, laptop, sata, adapter

I have bought an SSD for my notebook (Aspire E5-571G, 2014 model), but because I didn't need a disc drive, I bought a cheap adapter/caddy (it didn't have a package or model number) where I could put my previous hard drive (`ST500LT012-1DG142`) to replace the disc drive, which would give me SSD+HDD configuration. Unfortunately that did not work. I could somewhat painstakingly browse files but it would take a long time. The Windows Event Log was full of `The IO operation at logical block address 0xxxxxxx for Disk 1 (PDO name: \Device\xxxxxxxx) failed due to a hardware error`.

I ended up buying as twice expensive adapter from an online store that I have used before. Its model is `IB-AC640` and it came with a proper packaging, screws, et-cetera; basically everything you would expect. The situation remained the same.

I don't know where the problem is. Nothing changes whether notebook is connected to AC power or not - so the power isn't an issue. What's strange is that an old hard drive that only supported SATA-II would work inside the cheap adapter (I don't have the hard drive anymore so I can't test it with this adapter, also it wasn't mine so I couldn't test out if writes were working & their speeds).

**Update**
Connected the hard drive to my PC and it works just fine. Ran Windows disk check and it had found no errors.

**Update**
Ran SeaTools `Long Test` and it reported no errors.

---

[image: general info]
[image: SMART data]

Comment: Have you confirmed that the optical drive used SATA?  Were the BIOS settings for the HD set to RAID, ACHI, or something else, and has that changed?.  Have you purchased / borrowed an external USB HD enclosure ($10) to test to confirm that the HD is still working at all?  Have you swapped the HD back to its original spot to confirm it's still working?

Comment: @ChristopherHostage Everything is SATA. BIOS is set to UEFI and SATA mode is AHCI (can't change to anything else). I will try connecting the hard drive to my PC again to check if it's still alright (but judging by the SMART data I am positive that it's alright).

Comment: If the disk works OK in your PC maybe is a problem of the notebook USB port not supplying enough power to the disk. Has the external case dual USB connections, one for data/power and another for extra power? Had you tried plugging in both?

Comment: @AlbertoMartinez This is not a USB caddy.

Comment: @LittleHelper , some of these internal caddies do use internal USB leads from the laptop.  But it sounds like you've got a direct SATA connection.  Countering the idea about power : optical drives draw 10W-30W, while hard drives should only draw less than 10W

Comment: @ChristopherHostage Yeah, it's just a direct connection. It's a PCB but it has nothing on it. I checked the power consumption of the hard drive and the optical drive. The hard drive does need less power. I really have no idea why it's not working. Works fine on PC tho.

Comment: Sounds to me like a BIOS limitation. Can you try flashing a newer one?

Comment: @davidgo It's the latest one.